# Value Map Form Widgets in QGIS 3.x

Tags: qgis-3

I am using QGIS 3.6 and I have a list of cities and zipcodes for my county, in my geopackage address layer I have a field called zip I tried to set up a value map with city names in the "description" and zipcodes in the "value" fields of the  widget that should allow me to select the name of the city the address is associated with and for the value I wanted it to place the zipcode in the field however when I select the description (or the city name) it places the name of the city in the zip value and not the zipcode IF I change the widget back to a text edit type it has the zipcode in the field. What is happening?